UWP Release build (ARM64) fails to compile
I am having a hard time compiling Release build of UWP application (ARM64) when Serilog.Expressions package is installed. Debug build seems to work fine, however Release fails with following error:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.12-rel-31116-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(809,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-arm64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.12-rel-31116-00\tools\ARM64\ilc\Tools64\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\proj\TestAppBuild\obj\ARM64\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\TestAppBuild.rsp"' returned exit code -1073741819
To reproduce just open the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 and create a new project. Select C# template "Blank App (Universal Windows)". Add Serilog.Expressions NuGet package to the project. Select Release configuration for ARM64 and build the solution.
Please do you have some idea what could be causing this? Thanks.
(Here is also link to issue created on GitHub under serilog-expressions.)

Unless it's a UWP class library, or a Standard library; I don't think it will work.

It's a .NET Standard library so should pose no problems for the compiler (the compiler might produce warnings or errors, but shouldn't crash like this).

In case this might help someone - this bug was fixed in version 33220.00 of the Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler package.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
